# How to find current cursor position in SharePoint page edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I would like to insert some pre-formatted text on to the page, once a custom ribbon action is clicked. But may i know how to find the current cursor position in SharePoint page edit mode, so as to insert the text.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this can be done with javascript right ?

`function textbox()
{
    var ctl = document.getElementById('Javascript_example');
    var startPos = ctl.selectionStart;
    var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd;
    alert(startPos + ", " + endPos);
}`

Comment: the above is returning "undefined error"